# Finding the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

> This is my power series: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3}$$

I need to find the sum of it. Unfortunately, I have kind of no idea how to do it. I think I need to substitute with something. One of the series that I do know of is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$ which looks similar, $(4k-3)$ instead of $k$ but I really don't know how to substitute them.

Maybe I can do this, which will help, but I'm not sure?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^x \frac{x^{4k-4}}{4k-4} dx$$

Edit: I can see how I made a mistake with the integral.

At least with that I could have something like ${(x^4)}^{k-1}$? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k - 3} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{4(k-1)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x^4)^k = \frac1{1 - x^4}$$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k - 3}}{4k - 3} = \int \frac{dx}{1 - x^4} + C$$

Find $C$ by setting $x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I used a defined integral like Jack D'Aurizio's response, but this helped a lot too.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3} = \int_{0}^{x} z^{4k-4}\,dz $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3} = \int_{0}^{x}\sum_{k\geq 1} z^{4k-4}\,dz = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dz}{1-z^4} $$
but:
$$ \frac{1}{1-z^4} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2}+\frac{1}{1-z^2}\right) $$
so:

> $$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3} = \frac{1}{2}\,\arctan(x)+\frac{1}{4}\,\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
>   as soon as $|x|<1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Outline: Let 
$$f(t)=\sum_1^\infty t^{4k-4}.$$  The  power series we were given can be obtained by integrating the above series term by term from $0$ to $x$.

But $f(t)$ is a geometric series with common ratio $t^4$, and therefore has sum $\frac{1}{1-t^4}$.

Now carry out the integration (partial fractions).